# How to use the Android Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I was try to launch browser to do authorization in twitter, and want it to return to my app.
I was declare intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="appfortwitter" 
          android:host="com.pfs.safecrackerplus-callback" />                
</intent-filter>
```

In the app activity I was define method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
 ...
}
```

After authorization my app was launched again, but onCreate method was called instead of onNewIntent.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: i would suggest checking the intent in onCreate to know if it's the callback. i would guess that your activity has been destroyed by the time it comes back so it's being created, not getting a new intent.

Comment: Can I prevent my activity from destroying?

Comment: i don't think so. i think it automatically destroys it if it's in the background too long.

Comment: Are you using the `singleTop` flag? [`onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are authenticate using Web Browser instead twitter 3rd party api for Android.You never return on your activity when authentication is completed.Because its never notify you that authentication is completed or not.

Finally you should use twitter api for android instead doing it.

Comment: Is this an answer or just a rant that "everyone should use the Twitter API"?

Comment: I'l use the twitter4j-android-2.2.6, but it's not easy to understand how to use it. Sample code that I found uses that api and call browser too. If you know good samples for twitter please give me the link.

Comment: use this http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/pages/Home or http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Comment: Hi Sam Kindly let me know here is any better option instead of using twitter api.

Comment: Looking on the http://kenai.com I was find code like used in my app - th OAuth authentification method s used

Comment: no ;( As I understand, there is two ways how I can get access to twitter. 1) Always query/use login/password, 2) One time authorize my app using OAuth and then use the accessToken. I have allready created  app on twitter and want to use scond way, but currently can't understand ho to do it.